# An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1)

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to build my Ionic 2 project using `ionic cordova build android` but I keep getting this error. I don't know what is causing this error. Here is the error:

> cordova build android
>   × Running command - failed!

[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1):

```
    (truncated) ... by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv        failed
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1916)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1880)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1825)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:134)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3375)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3368)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:72)
    ... 7 more
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:593)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:532)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:940)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    ... 14 more
    Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
    Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException:        java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1551)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.available(AppInputStream.java:60)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.available(BufferedInputStream.java:410)
    at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.available(MeteredStream.java:170)
    at sun.net.www.http.KeepAliveStream.close(KeepAliveStream.java:85)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:181)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.close(HttpURLConnection.java:3448)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:91)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:51)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:62)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1916)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1880)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1825)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:134)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3375)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3368)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:72)
    ... 7 more
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:593)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:532)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:940)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    ... 14 more
    Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
```

Comment: What are the plugin are you using? Could you brief more on your project contents

Answer (score -1):

for me this worked :

go to network settings -> ipv4 proprities -> change dns and put google's dns :

8.8.8.8

8.8.4.4